# Install a private add-on in GSuite Gmail

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, google-apps-script-add-on

Is it possible to install a private add-on (that isn't published in the GSuite Marketplace) in my organization's Gmail?

If so, how can I do that?

I went through all the settings under Apps Settings of the Google Admin console, but I couldn't find how to do it. I couldn't find any documentation either.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/publish to allow other users on your domain to install your add-on you should give them the deployment ID.

> Publishing Gmail Add-ons
>
> Publishing add-ons allows them to be used by other users. While a few
>   add-ons have been made available in the G Suite Marketplace for users
>   to install, it is not currently possible to publish your own add-on to
>   the Marketplace.
>
> In the meantime, you can install add-ons you have developed to test
>   them. You can also install add-ons created by other users in your
>   domain if they give you the add-on's deployment ID.
>
> If you'd like your add-on to be considered for publication, please
>   fill out this form to be notified as we begin accepting additional
>   listings.

The instructions for installing unplublished add-ons are published on https://developers.google.com/gmail/add-ons/how-tos/install-unpublished